# How can I tell if a shell is spawned by sFTP with "Escape to local shell"?

Tags: shell, sftp

After connecting to a remote machine with command `sftp hostname`, `!` could be typed within the `sftp` prompt to "Escape to local shell`.

Is it possible to tell whether I'm in a shell spawned by `sftp`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no simple way to check (e.g., there's no environment variable that identifies your shell as one that was started from sftp).

You could walk up the process tree and see if one of your ancestors is an `sftp` process:

```
#!/bin/bash

pid=$$
while :; do
  # if we reach pid 1, we know we're not a child of an sftp process
  [[ $pid -eq 1 ]] && break

  # get parent of $pid
  ppid=$(ps -o ppid= $pid)

  # get the command associated with $ppid
  cmd=$(ps -o cmd= -p $ppid)

  # check if it was sftp
  if [[ $cmd =~ sftp ]]; then
    echo "Running under sftp"
    exit
  fi

  pid=$ppid
done

echo "Not a child of sftp"
```

Comment: Since we're walking up the process tree, `$PPID` isn't useful to us.  E.g., if you put the above in a shell script and ran it, `$PPID` would point to your *shell*, not to `sftp`. We need to go up multiple levels.

Comment: (For context, a previous commenter had pointed out that `$PPID` is available in the shell and wondered why I wasn't using that.)

Answer (score 1):

```
% sftp myhost
Connected to myhost.
sftp> !sh
$ if pgrep -s 0 sftp >/dev/null; then echo 'in sftp session'; fi
in sftp session
```

This uses `pgrep` to test whether there is a `sftp` command running in the same session as the current shell.  If there is, then this shell was likely started from that `sftp`.

If your `pgrep` supports the `-q` option, use that instead of redirecting the output to `/dev/null`.

For a quick visual inspection, you could also use `pstree -s -p "$$"` (on Linux; `pstree -p "$$"` on some BSDs, depending on `pstree` implementation).  This would show you the process tree for the current process, and you would hopefully be able to spot `sftp` in there by eye.